# Delete a single cookie from Internet Explorer 11 F12 Dev Tools

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I am running Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1. I'd like to delete a single cookie from the F12 Developer Tools. How do I do this? If I right-click on a cookie, there are no operations, except to copy information out of this window.

I would expect there to be an option to delete a specific cookie, or clear cookies for a specific DNS domain.

[image: IE11 F12 Dev Tools]

Answer (score 5):

You can't delete a single cookie from in the F12 developers tools. You can delete all. You can use the document.cookie API to interact with cookies but it isn't pretty :(.

We have a feature on the F12 backlog to add such feature though and I'll +1 it.